# How to ask my manager to upgrade my hardware?

Tags: new-job, germany

I'm starting as a new employee as a software engineer in a German company. When I did the interview, I found the hardware pretty old (2011) and the computer seemed slow. It seemed to me that most of my team members have the same hardware. I would like to get new hardware simply because this is slow!

My questions:

1. How can I approach my manager to make him change my hardware/computer?
2. Are there some standard policies regarding changing the hardware among software companies? I. e. when should they change them or so?
3. Is it normal and okay to ask to change the hardware (since I'm a new hire and fresh from graduate school) or is it considered not a normal thing in the software industry?

Comment: In your past few posts you have suggested your co-worker are not competent in math or research because they don't have CS degrees, how not to look like a slacker, and now how to ask for a hardware upgrade as a new employee.   You need to put your head down, get along, and get it done.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** You need to make a busines case for why you need upgraded hardware.

Really, unless there is a cost benefit (improved productivity) or risk (hardware failure), then there is no incentive for an organisation to upgrade its hardware.  If they are reticent to do so, then you need to make the case to your manager as to *why* you need good hardware.  Demonstrate a cost-benefit analysis and show how much more productive you will be! :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1- how can I approach my manager to make him change my hardware/computer?

Policies and procedures differ by company.  Generally asking a coworker how to do it is the best bet.  The internet doesn't know how your employer does business.  However, if all of your coworkers also have old computers, the answer is probably that you can't do so successfully because your boss is cheap.

> 2- are there some standard policies regarding changing the hardware among software companies? i.e when should they change them or so?

Something like that would be nice...

> 3- Is it normal and okay to ask to change the hardware (since I'm a new hire and fresh from graduate school) or is it considered not a normal thing in the software industry?!

Don't rock the boat is generally good advice when just starting a new job.  You can ask; but as I noted above it doesn't sound like your company is going to care.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal in this industry to have out-of-date, crappy slow hardware. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't ask for newer and better equipment.

From my experience, the larger the organization, the larger the desktop IT team, and the slower the upgrades happen over time.

At the end of the day, though, the company is likely spending more money having you work on slow equipment than if they'd just fork out the money to get you new stuff.

So, yes, definitely ask for new equipment. If you don't get it, start documenting the amount of time you waste every day due to the slow hardware (reboot times, build times, etc.)